# How to add images on the layout with delay?

Tags: android, layout

I have a trouble. I need to add and show a couple images(a quantity will be calculated before) to layout with delay, but they appears in the same moment.

Here is me code:

Handler:

```
h = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handle message!");
            int delay = msg.arg2;
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Position position = (Position)msg.obj;
            int img = msg.arg1;
            int topMargin = getMarginInPixels(position.getY());
            int leftMargin = getMarginInPixels(position.getX());
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            iv.setImageResource(img);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.topMargin = topMargin;
            lp.leftMargin = leftMargin;
            iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            rl.addView(iv); 
        }
    };
```

And in the loop:

```
Message m = h.obtainMessage(0, img, delay, newPosition);
            h.sendMessage(m);
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handler work with UI, try halt on you Background Thread, and from it call Handler.
like

```
new Thread( new Runnable(){
 for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
   SystemClock.sleep(1000);//
   Message m = h.obtainMessage(0, img,newPosition);
            h.sendMessage(m);
 }
}
).start();
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why my code does not work? Thank you again!

Comment: The Handler it's wrapper between background Thread wich can be do long time operations and UI wich must interact with user while long time operation process. So Hander work in UI thread and if you halt it - it's halt UI. Exist 3 ways to do background operations: Handler,AsyncTask<> and Services. More info search here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html